# How to host an ASP.NET application that uses Oracle 11g on a machine that has only Oracle 12c?

Tags: asp.net, oracle11g, oracle12c, odac, oracleclient

My ASP.NET application runs on a Windows Server 2008 R2 server. Oracle 11g is installed.

I deployed this application to a Windows Server 2016 server. Oracle 12c is installed in this server (11g is not supported).

When I run the application, I get this error:

> Could not load file or assembly Oracle.DataAccess

If I copy Oracle 11g dll (`Oracle.DataAccess.dll`) to application's bin folder, I see this message:

> The provide is not compatible with the version of Oracle client

Is there any way to make this application run without installing Oracle 11g or changing application code?

[image]

Comment: It would be the best way to start using managed driver instead of ODAC but It's not an option for this case unfortunately @mason

Comment: The reason is that we have to do this for about 20 applications and changing & recompiling the code is not in the project scope

Comment: They use different namespaces, correct? We import and use "Oracle.DataAccess.Client" in all over the code. How to start using "Oracle.ManagedDataAccess" without changing the code?

Comment: why dont you include the oracle DLL in the project and use that locally. add those dlls to your project as "Add new Item". click on properties and set "local copy=true". make sure you have the Xcopy version of the drivers

Comment: Good suggestion @Sujit.Warrier but we are trying to avoid making any change to the project as I mentioned. We have 20 applications and even a simple change will require recompiling them which means business user involvement, extensive testing, and change managements procedures. You may know the process in enterprise companies

Comment: then why dont you just copy the dlls to the bin folder after deployment.no building required.

Comment: I tried. As I mentioned in the post, it gives this error: "The provide is not compatible with the version of Oracle client"

Comment: you copies 12c right? why dont you copy the 11g dlls

Comment: Sorry for the typo. I corrected the post. I tried copying 11g dll

Answer (score 1):

**If** i understand well your application is linked to 11gR2 dll of Oracle.DataAccess.dll.

Can you check the version of the dll that is in your path (probably in the GAC, but not always) ?

What do you have in this section of Web.config (sample taken from my web site) ? Does this match the dll in your path ? :

```
<runtime>
    <!-- This prevents the Windows Event Log from frequently logging that HMAC1 is being used (when the other party needs it). -->
    <legacyHMACWarning enabled="0" />
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
        <!-- Oracle -->
        <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="Oracle.DataAccess" publicKeyToken="89B483F429C47342" culture="neutral" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.65535.65535.65535" newVersion="4.122.1.0" />
        </dependentAssembly>
        <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess" publicKeyToken="89b483f429c47342" culture="neutral" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="4.0.0.0 - 4.65535.65535.65535" newVersion="4.122.1.0" />
        </dependentAssembly>
```

Above I am remapping all versions of the driver to the driver installed on my server. It usually works fine, unless you are activelly using something that is only present in a "up" version.

Be sure to check the version of your dll (the version above is for a a 12.2 driver).

Answer (score 0):

You mean, " without installing Oracle **11g**, don't you? 12c is installed right now. At least, that's what I understood - application runs OK on [Server 2008 + 11g], and now you want it to run on [Server 2016 + 12c].

If it turns out that I'm right and that you'd have to install 11g onto Server 2016, then you could install Oracle Client software, but - if you ask me - I'd rather install Oracle 11g Express Edition (XE) database. Here's why:

- installation is easy (a few NEXT clicks)

  - just make sure to install it into its own Oracle Home (i.e. directory, one that is different from the one that contains 12c)
- it won't take much space
- set it (in "Services") to be started *manually* (i.e. *never*), as you don't really need to use it as a *database*, but only its DLLs or whatever your application needs, so it won't take any resources (but hard disk space)
- it contains everything you might need (including utilities, such as export/import & SQL*Loader, network support)
- whenever I needed something, I was much happier with XE installation than the Client installation (but OK, that's probably me, not being capable of using Client properly)

If it turns out that I'm wrong, oh well, wait for someone else's & far better opinion.

Comment: You're right. I meant "without installing Oracle 11g" (I edited my question). However, you are suggesting to install 11g. I am not allowed to install it (company policy - 11g is not supported in 2016 so it cannot be installed)

Comment: I understand. Though, reading through forums, I've seen that people still use 8.1.7 and Forms 6i, so I presume that 11gXE would live long & prosper on your system, without actually doing *anything* but providing missing pieces. I hope that there IS solution for your problem and that you'll manage to find it. Best of luck!